# Significance of orthonormal basis in wavelet analysis

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, wavelets

I've recently been looking into wavelet analysis and I have the question: What is the importance of wavelets having an orthogonal basis, say as opposed to a bi-orthogonal basis or otherwise? I'm fairly new to a lot of functional analysis so I've not seen the importance of this property so far in what I've researched. Many thanks.

Comment: It makes them easier to work with. With a general basis you run into cross terms when trying to compute $L^2$ norms and there's just a lot more bookkeeping involved.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42040/why-do-we-want-to-have-orthogonal-bases-in-decompositions

Comment: @Tom perhaps you could suggest an example of what you suggest over bi-orthogonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Orthogonal wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_wavelet) allows for analysis and synthesis filters to be the same and only one filter (and it's mirrored alternating signs). For [biorthogonal wavelets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biorthogonal_wavelet) you need two different filters and their respective mirrored alternating signs. So you have more degrees of freedom in designing biorthogonal wavelets, although the implementation will be slightly more complicated.